# Unable to connect background Image with static file Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have following html template

```
        <div class="owl-slide cover" style="background-image: url({%  static 'img/slides/slide_home_2.jpg'%});">
        </div>
```

But I am not able to load static background.

my static directory is same as it is in django project path along with templates.
here is my part of setting.py for static files

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/',)
```

Everything seems look ok but my background is not working any suggestion will be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to hear that. I don't know if you have solved you issue meanhwile.

In my settings.py I have the following STATIC setting

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

Within every Django-App in my Django-Website I have a directory like this

```
<app-name>/static/<app-name>/...
```

And within the templates I am using the following code:
At the very beginning

```
{% load static %}
```

What I also recognized in your code is that your path starts with "img/"
If I want to refer to an image then I use

```
{% static "<app-name>/image.png" %}
```

Comment: I solved it thanks for ans I was missing to connect one static file that actually was js file

Answer (score 0):

at least when deploy on a server I have to execute the following command so Django collects all static files and make it available.

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

Maybe this helps?

Comment: sadly does not help :(